# How to navigate in jquery ui accordion when one panel is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an jquery ui accordion. In every panel there is next or/and previous button that navigates me through the accordion panels. This is working. On one panel i have a select html element. In this element i can choose an option. If option1: don't disable me the second accordion section. If option2: disable the second section.
This is also working. 
The problem is when i select the option2 and the secend section is disable i can still access it via the button. How can i disable it and go to the third section ?

my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wgjfovnf/

```
$(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
$('#accordion button[name=tab-control]').on('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var control = ($(this).is('.next') ? 1 : -1);
   $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', ($('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active') + control));
});

$('#selectSection').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() === 's2') {
    $('#ui-id-3').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
  else {
    $('#ui-id-3').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable button, if your `option2` is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable `next button` while you selecting `option2`

Here you can try this

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
$('#accordion button[name=tab-control]').on('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if($(this).attr('skip') != undefined) {
      var control = ($(this).is('.next') ? 2 : -2);
   } else {
      var control = ($(this).is('.next') ? 1 : -1);
   }
   $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active',
      ($('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active') + control)
   );
});

$('#selectSection').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() === 's2') {
    $('.next').attr("skip","true");
    $('.previous').attr("skip","true");
    $('#ui-id-3').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
  else {
   $('.next').removeAttr("skip");
   $('.previous').removeAttr("skip");
    $('#ui-id-3').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
  }
});
});
```

Here is the solution check it.

Comment: i would like to keep the button functions. just skip the one accordion disabled panel and move from first to third section.

Comment: @GregOstry You can check now i just update my answer